# What is the best attack on AES with a half known key?

Tags: encryption, aes

If I have a 16 bytes key and I encrypt a text block (1KB) with AES, and the attacker knows half of the key (let's say the first half), how does it weakens the encryption?

Comment: Hint: what does the AES standard say about the bits of the key?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.